# Why vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties has no return value

Tags: vulkan

Most functions in Vulkan that query for an array of items usually follow a similar API style (for example [vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices.html)).

Is there any reason that [vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties.html) does not return a `VkResult` despite having nearly identical API usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions return a `VkResult` if they can fail. `vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices` can fail for a variety of reasons (out-of-memory).

`vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties` is not permitted to fail, so it doesn't need to return anything. Implementations therefore must allocate any memory for holding those properties when it created the `VkPhysicalDevice` to begin with (or otherwise must implement them in a way that doesn't allocate memory here).